# Advice on Core 2 Duo upgrade path

Tags: upgrade, motherboard, intel-core2, multi-core

I'm a .Net developer who also loves playing the latest computer games.  My current rig has lasted me well but it's time to upgrade the old girl to something faster.  As I see it, my two options for upgrading are:

1. Upgrading my CPU and keeping my MoBo + RAM; or
2. Upgrading to an i5/i7 and getting a new Mobo + RAM as well.

I'm leaning towards option 1 just to get full usage over my current infrastructure, but I'm unsure what the limits of my MoBo are? I've got 3 Gigs of RAM and I'm OK with that. My current specs are (from CPU-Z):

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E6400 @ 2.13Ghz (Conroe 65nm) (Socket 775 LGA)
- MotherBoard: Foxconn 965X7AA
- Chipset: [Northbridge] Intel P965/G965 rev. C2  [Southbridge] Intel 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R) rev. B0

So, please help me work out what's the **fastest/most powerful CPU** I can put in this?  Can I go Quad?  I've just got no idea.

As an example of what I'm looking for.. could I upgrade to either of these?

- [Intel Core 2 Duo E8600 Wolfdale 3.33GHz 65W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115054)
- [Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650 3.0GHz 95W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115130)

thanks in advance!

PS I'm sorry if I missed out a stat you needed to work this out.. if asked I can provide any CPU-Z stat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the newegg search above wasn't the answer.  I bought an E7600 Duo 3.06 GHz, but my motherboard couldn't handle it and wouldn't boot.

I later found out that the 965-based "Northbridge" was limited in what CPUs it could use..  the complete list of compatible CPUs that can be used are listed here:

[Intel Specs on P965](http://ark.intel.com/chipset.aspx?familyID=22754)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your 965-based motherboard's FSB might be your limiting factor -- it tops out at 1066MHz, which I don't think the two CPUs you linked are capable of operating at 1066MHz FSB, versus the native 1333Mhz FSB.

Back in Pentium 4 days, you couldn't use 800Mhz FSB P4s on a board that only did 400,533MHz FSB -- I'm not sure if that still holds true in today's processors.

Here's a link to 1066/800Mhz FSB CPUs if it turns out the 1333MHz FSB processor won't work on 1066Mhz boards.

- http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&N=2%2050001157%2040000343%201051707842&PropertyCodeValue=511%3A7412%2C511%3A7411&bop=And&ActiveSearchResult=False&Order=PRICED

AnandTech Bench compares CPUs (pick a benchmark at the top) -- to give you an idea how much of a boost you get in apps that are single-threaded and multi-threaded.

- http://www.anandtech.com/bench/default.aspx?b=25

I use Photoshop frequently, so going from a P4 to a Core 2 Duo was a huge jump.  But say if I had a Core 2 Quad Q9650 right now -- an i7-920 doesn't quite seem like a upgrade I'd go for.  ymmv.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions as well!  Your response was exactly the help I needed!